# jQuery: Function calls twice resulting in strange behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jQuery for altering a dropdown menu:

```
function getStatus(item) {
    return $(item).hasClass("active")
}

$(document).on("page:change", function () {
    $(".nav-element.parent").click(function(e) {
        el = $(this)
        if ( getStatus(el) ) { 
            $(this).toggleClass("active") 
            $(this).find(".nav-child-element").slideToggle()
        } else { 
            $(".nav-element.parent").removeClass("active")
            $(".nav-child-element").slideUp();
            $(this).addClass("active")
            $(this).find(".nav-child-element").slideDown();
        }
    })
});
```

and the function works properly unless I navigate to another page, and then go back, using the browser back button.  Then when I click on the `$(".nav-element.parent")` element, the loop occurs twice effectively opening the dropdown.

Oddly enough, when I change the `$(".nav-element.parent").click(function(e) {` line to `$(document).on("click", ".nav-element.parent", function(e) {` the loop occurs 3 times.  I'm not sure how to fix this and adding `e.stopPropagation();` at the end has no effect.

Comment: Does this happen if you hit refresh after hitting back?  You most likely are experiencing this because the handlers aren't getting removed from memory. You should remove the handlers in the `window.beforeunload` event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the `.off` method to remove the previous event listener before it gets assigned again.

```
function getStatus(item) {
    return $(item).hasClass("active")
}

$(document).on("page:change", function () {

    $(".nav-element.parent").off().on('click', function(e) {
        el = $(this)
        if ( getStatus(el) ) { 
            $(this).toggleClass("active") 
            $(this).find(".nav-child-element").slideToggle()
        } else { 
            $(".nav-element.parent").removeClass("active")
            $(".nav-child-element").slideUp();
            $(this).addClass("active")
            $(this).find(".nav-child-element").slideDown();
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Amazing.  I don't know how I've missed that!